# Can I copy a folder and its subfolders to another folder in Lotus Notes 7?

Tags: lotus-notes

New user of Lotus Notes here. Can a folder and its subfolders be copied to another folder in the tree structure?

I want to have a template structure of folders in place and used it to populate the content of new folders I want to create. This is in the same mailbox, not between mailboxes.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I'm pretty sure that isn't possible. You could probably make some kind of toolbar button to script folder creation, but beyond that I don't think it's possible.